# Adding variable in SQL command not working with Select statement

Tags: python, mysql, sqlcommand

Code:

```
x = int(id_[0])
select_query = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE id = %s"
cursor.execute(select_query,x)
results = cursor.fetchone()
```

I am using mySQL in Python. This is the error I get:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line

It works when I get rid of the variable and just add a random id like 1.

Comment: The second argument to `cursor.execute()` should be an iterable: `cursor.execute(select_query,(x,))`

Comment: You definitely haven't quotes `%s` in your actual query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add string delimiters around your `%s`, so SQL is trying to process that as a variable name or column name. Furthermore, for regex expressions like the one you have, try using `LIKE` instead of `=`

To fix the SQL syntax errors, your query should look something like this:

```
x = int(id_[0])
select_query = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE id LIKE '%s'"
cursor.execute(select_query,x)
results = cursor.fetchone()
```